# Phaser - error: Cannot read property 'on' of null

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm working on a simple game using Phaser.

My code:

```
preload() {
  this.load.image('player', 'img/player.png');
}

create() {
  var player = this.add.sprite(100,100,'player');

  player.inputEnabled = true;
  player.input.on('pointerdown', () => {
    this.scene.stop('ThisScene');
    this.scene.start('NextScene');
  })
}
```

The game should switch from one scene to another when you click on the sprite 'player'. Unfortunately, this gives an error: Cannot read property 'on' of null

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it doesn't work is that you've got a mixture of Phaser 2 and Phaser 3 code here. The `inputEnabled = true` comes from Phaser 2, and the use of the `on` event listener is from Phaser 3.

You don't state which version you're using, though, so I'll assume 3 and fix the code for that:

```
preload() {
  this.load.image('player', 'img/player.png');
}

create() {
  var player = this.add.sprite(100,100,'player');

  player.setInteractive();

  player.on('pointerdown', () => {
    this.scene.start('NextScene');
  })
}
```

When a Game Object is enabled for input, you listen for the events directly on the Game Object itself, not the `input` component.

Answer (score 1):

Have you check if the **`pointerdown event`** is working? Let's try to replace the line **`player.inputEnabled = true;`** with the line **`player.setInteractive();`**. Then, do a **`console.log('pointerdown event working')`** inside the **`event listener`**:

```
create() {
  var player = this.add.sprite(100,100,'player');

  player.setInteractive();

  player.input.on('pointerdown', () => {
    console.log('pointerdown event working');

    this.scene.stop('ThisScene');
    this.scene.start('NextScene');
  })
}
```

Let me know if that works...If not, we'll know that the `event` is firing & we'll take it from there.